# Asp.Net Menu control with Tab Style (Rounded Corners)

Tags: asp.net, menu, rounded-corners

Can any body give me a better idea to come up with a Asp.net 2.0 Menu control with rounded corners?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set CSS up with rounded graphics. If you want the selected tab to have a different color, you can use the window shade scripts from a variety of sites. Consider looking at Exploding Boy:

http://exploding-boy.com/images/cssmenus/menus.html

You can get the graphics, CSS and JavaScript from this site. If you want the ASP.NET menu control to look the best, use the CSS friendly adapter for the menu (downloadable from www.asp.net) as it uses the unordered list  method of setting up menus.